# Different result between urllib and aiohttp

Tags: python, urllib, aiohttp

So basically i'm trying to get the currently playing track from online radio direct link (Example -
http://air.radiorecord.ru:8101/rr_320).

Firstly i found something in the internet, written with urllib, my application is asynchronous so i needed to use aiohttp. With urllib it worked perfectly, while aiohttp sometimes just can't find anything. Pls help :(

before:

```
def get_now(self, session):
    request = urllib.Request(self.data.get('url'),headers={'Icy-MetaData': 1} ) # request metadata

    response = urllib.urlopen(request)
    metadata = response.headers

    metaint = int(response.headers['icy-metaint'])
    for _ in range(10):  # title may be empty initially, try several times
        response.read(metaint)  # skip to metadata
        metadata_length = struct.unpack('B', response.read(1))[0] * 16  # length byte
        metadata = response.read(metadata_length).rstrip(b'\0')

        # extract title from the metadata
        m = re.search(br"StreamTitle='([^']*)';", metadata)
        if m:
            title = m.group(1)
            if title:
                break
            else:
                return "No title found"
    return title.decode('utf8', errors='replace')  

except:
    return "No title found"
```

after:

```
async def get_now(self, session):
    
    async with session.get(self.stream_url, headers={'Icy-MetaData': "1"}) as resp:
        
        content = resp.content

        metadata = resp.headers
        metaint = int(metadata['icy-metaint'])

        for _ in range(30):
            await content.read(metaint)
            metadata_length = struct.unpack('B', await content.read(1))[0] * 16  # length byte
            metadata = (await content.read(metadata_length)).rstrip(b'\0')

            m = re.search(br"StreamTitle='([^']*)';", metadata)
            if m:
                title = m.group(1)
                if title:
                    return title.decode('utf8', errors='replace')
                else:
                    return "No title found"
            

        return "Nothing found"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below is always able to detect the current track (in around **400ms**) but instead of processing only part of the chunk it checks the whole chunk as it's read:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import re


async def get_now(stream_url, session):
    headers={"Icy-MetaData": "1"}
    async with session.get(stream_url, headers=headers) as resp:
        for _ in range(10):
            data = await resp.content.read(8192)
            m = re.search(br"StreamTitle='([^']*)';", data.rstrip(b"\0"))
            if m:
                title = m.group(1)
                if title:
                    return title.decode("utf8", errors="replace")
                else:
                    return "No title found"
    return "Nothing found"


async def get_track():
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    stream_url = "http://air.radiorecord.ru:8101/rr_320"
    result = await get_now(stream_url, session)
    print(f"result: {result}")
    await session.close()


asyncio.run(get_track())
```

Result on my computer (CPU usage is very low on a quite old CPU: *i7-3517U*):

```py
[ionut@ionut-pc ~]$ time python test.py 
result: Record Club - Nejtrino & Baur

real    0m0.401s
user    0m0.198s
sys 0m0.031s
```

Comment: so how do if this?

Comment: You just need to adapt the **minimal working example** above to use your class (basically get the `stream_url` from `self` rather than a parameter). The `get_track` function is only there to test the `get_now` function.

Comment: oh frick yeh. Thank you bro :D